# New cat won't stop meowing

Tags: cats, behavior, training, adoption

I have a new cat from the Humane Society that was once a street cat. It's about a year old and it won't stop meowing whenever it knows there's a human around. I've had it about a week and have kept it in my room, as per the humane societies recommendation. When I'm in another part of my apartment and I am quiet, it will eventually stop meowing. When it's on my lap or sleeping it sometimes stops meowing.

Essentially, if it knows someone can give it attention, it will scream and scream. I let it out of my room once and it ran to the center of each other room, one after the other, screaming loudly.

I purchased Feliway about 4 days ago to help with the transition but so far no luck.

What can I do to keep from driving myself and my neighbours insane?
Will the cat always be this noisy and needy?

Answer (score 7):

This is early days, and the cat is not used to having a home and human security. Many street cats will hiss at humans, but luckily your cat is wanting affection, which ultimately will make a more loving pet, one that you are able to be close to and not need to coax out of hiding.

When you see the cat or she meows for you, go to her and pick her up or pat her. Talk to her and praise her. They don't understand words, but they can pick up feelings from people and tone of voice.

A pet is a time commitment and for any pet, the first weeks and months are the settling in time where you're both getting to know each other. Patience is a key here for every owner. We need to lead for the pet and understand that they are in an unfamiliar circumstance and need reassurance, whatever behaviours they are showing. In this case it is straight forward.

Your cat is clingy, and she will settle over time, but sounds like she will be the sort of cat that will always want to be around you. That can be annoying at times when my cat wants to climb on my keyboard, between me and my screen, as he sees where my attention is focused and wants to insert himself into that.

Plenty of pats when she's not meowing (if possible) and another trick is to pick her up, give her a cuddle and a smooch and then put her down and ask her to follow you. Get her used to not being abandoned and you can train her to follow you without panic, as when you put her down, she still has your attention.

It will take some consistent effort. If you put a lot of time into this for the next few days, you'll notice she will start to settle. If you are pushing her away or agitated with her, she will feel insecure. She is terrified, as she does not understand what this home is and how long it will last. She's gone from the street, to a shelter and now your home. Imagine how lost such a small creature would feel and remember to just simply reassure her with a kind attitude. I have found kindness goes a long way when dealing with pets.

Let me know how this goes and if you need more assistance.

Comment: IDK, I am pretty sure my cat can understand words...

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer I think my pets understand some key words and phrases - I didn't want to open that can of worms

Answer (score 3):

I do want to point out though that it may suffer from separation anxiety from the excessive meowing and attention seeking. If you do have suspicions of this, I suggest you consult a vet, although that is taking it to the worst case scenario.

As for putting an end to excessive meowing, try your best to not give in when she seeks your attention in the wrong way. Only give her attention when she's calm and quiet, reward with lots of treats and cuddles!

This behaviour will probably subside as you get to know your furry fried, after all its only been a week!

Answer (score 3):

All the suggestions and input given here is  sound advice. The current situation with your new kitty will resolve with as already mentioned, patience and of your course your loving attention.

Additionally, she is going to need a perch of some kind, i.e., cat tree or equivalent that is *her territory*.

> I let it out of my room once and it ran to center of each other room , one after the other, screaming loudly.

Basically, this is an obvious cry for attention and her expression of distress. As others have said, this is a new situation for you both and given her history, she is displaying her insecurity in her new surroundings.

Give her love, attention,  a cat tree (or these great perches) and this will soon be resolved.
[image: perch]

Answer (score 1):

Your cat is scared, and does not feel that it has anywhere safe to run to. My (street) cat did exactly this when I first invited him into our home and then shut the back door. It immediately ran into the centre of the living room (the largest room in the house), looking for safety. Only when I opened the back door so that it could escape if it wanted to, did it calm down. He still preferred to live outside for some time, but eventually he decided that it was OK to stay and didn't mind the back door being closed.

If you can't allow your cat to go outside, then get him a hidey-hole. This could be a ready-made cat house, or something as simple as a large cardboard box with a hole cut in it.

Another thing that you could do is to establish set feeding times for your cat. However, if you do and the cat accepts it, it will hold you to it.