# New cat stressed

Tags: cats, behavior, adoption

Hi I adopted a cat from the spca today who was abandoned. When we first picked him up he was super loving and was taking as much pets as he could. We placed him in a room and he was meowing and rubbing on things, just seemed very curious. As the day has gone on suddenly he started meowing super loudly as if he was looking for someone and he just sounds super stressed. I went in once to check on him and his tail was puffed down, back arched and meowing super loudly. I picked him up not realizing his tail was puffed and he immediately started screaming. He won’t let me get anywhere near him now any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Not a full answer, but when moving a cat to a new home, it is normal for them to be easily startled for a while. They do not yet know the smells and sounds that are normal and no cause for concern. As far as interacting with him goes since there was a negative experience, i.e. being picked up while already in a defensive posture, best advice is to not approach him, but let him approach you. Sit down in the same room and don't look directly at him, wait for him to come to you. Having a treat ready does not hurt, but be patient and let him decide when he is ready to approach.

Comment: please have a look in the following two questions and let us know, if or if not the answers are helpful for you.

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26142/new-cat-meows-constantly

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16783/new-cat-wont-stop-meowing

Comment: I have a lot of ideas about what you could have done before you move. But now, there is little to do.